# How can I add a delay to a change of .css state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
  $(document)
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'progress !important' })
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'default !important' })
    });
```

Is there a way that I can prolong the cursor progress state by 2 seconds. Right now it comes and goes too quick. In other words I would like to have the cursor change to "progress" for at least a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit:*

Try use `window.setTimeout`.

```
  var timer = null;

  $(document)
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'progress !important' });
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
           $(this).css({ 'cursor': 'default !important' });
        }, 2000);

    });
```

Comment: That won't work. Delay has no effect on the css function.

Comment: Could someone provide a fiddle to check it out. I also a bit doubt of `delay`. However, everything might happen.

Comment: @Ariel You are right, updated my answer.

Comment: @xdazz - Did you get this to work. I tried your code but still don't see the cursor changing.

Comment: Dose `$(document).css({ 'cursor': 'progress !important' });` change your cursor? if doesn't, that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(this).delay('1000').css({ 'cursor': 'progress !important' });
```

Comment: That won't work. Delay has no effect on the css function.

Comment: See the edit.it works now(for me also)

Comment: Have you actually tried that? The docs say it won't work, and I just tried it and the docs are correct: it does not work.

Comment: But in fiddle i tried it,and i get

Comment: Sry its not the effect of delay,i used fadeIn() in my fiddle,when i removed it,i shouldnt work,thanks Ariel,i learned new thing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.delay(1000, function(){
//Do anything after 1 second
});
```

Comment: You might as well use `setTimeout()` if you are going to do that, unless you specifically need to interact with the jQuery effect queue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use setTimeout ( http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp );

setTimeout("javascript function",milliseconds);

Do what you want to to in "javascript function" replace milliseconds with how long you want to wait.